# Can I easily specify monospace text in XamarinForms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to use monospaced text in XamarinForms.  Can this be done without figuring out the specific suitable font families for all the platforms?  I see in Xamarin without forms that there is a System.Drawing.FontFamily.GenericMonospace property that looks like it would work.

Comment: I've been googling this for a while too. Seems like it isn't too much to ask.